# Two dimensional array initilization in Mplab XC16

Tags: c, mplab, xc16

I have defined the two-dimensional array inside the ***typedef struct*** as,

```
#define MAX_STAGES_IIR 20

 typedef struct {
     float A[MAX_STAGES_IIR]; // Input Gain
     float a[MAX_STAGES_IIR][2]; // input stage coff
     
     float b[MAX_STAGES_IIR][3]; // output stage coff
    // float B[MAX_STAGES_IIR]; // output gain
     
     float Xdash[MAX_STAGES_IIR][2];
     
     float iir_k[MAX_STAGES_IIR];//
     float iir_r[MAX_STAGES_IIR];//

     float iir_outStage[MAX_STAGES_IIR];
}IIRFilter;
```

When assigning values to the array use this method,

```
IIRFilter BpfHX_iir1;

    BpfHX_iir1.A = { 0.131726 , 0.131726 , 0.12435, 1.0f }; // gain 

    BpfHX_iir1.a = {{-1.63410, 0.82662},{-1.87089, 0.91410},{-1.6652, 0.7513}}; // a

    BpfHX_iir1.b = {{1, 0, -1},{1, 0, -1},{1, 0, -1}}; // b
```

but the Mplab XC16 can't build this method.

gives the same error message for all three arrays,

**expected expression before '{' token**

**expected expression before '{' token**

**expected expression before '{' token**

what is the reason for that?

is there a correct method to do that in XC16?

Comment: Do you want _initialization_ (values determined when the object is defined)? Or _assignment_ (values determined after the object is defined)?

Comment: assign the values after the object is defined; the initialization was inside the .h file. I want to assign the vales to the array inside the main.

Comment: `BpfHX_iir1.A = { 0.131726 , 0.131726 , 0.12435, 1.0f };` looks like 4 array elements are wanting to be assigned.  What about the other 16?

Comment: `BpfHX_iir1.(member name)` is only used to set 3 of the 7 members, what about the other 4?

Comment: others are zeros, elements don't matter if `#define MAX_STAGES_IIR 4` and BpfHX_iir1.A = { 0.131726 , 0.131726 , 0.12435, 1.0f }; gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `BpfHX_iir1` in the usual way.
Use `float` constants and not `double` ones for the `float` array.  (Append an `f`.)

```
IIRFilter BpfHX_iir1 = { //
  .A = {0.131726f, 0.131726f, 0.12435f, 1.0f}, //
  .a = { {-1.63410f, 0.82662f}, {-1.87089f, 0.91410f}, {-1.6652f, 0.7513f}}, //
  .b = { {1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}, {1, 0, -1}} //
};
```

All members of `BpfHX_iir1` will be initialized.  Those not explicitly coded above will have a zero bit-pattern.

---

To *assign* an array <sup>*1</sup> via `memcpy()` at a later time is easy if the compiler is C99 compliant.  Use a *compound literal*.

```
void foobar(void) {
  IIRFilter BpfHX_iir1;
  //                   v-------------------------------- compound literal ---------v
  memcpy(BpfHX_iir1.A, (float[MAX_STAGES_IIR]){0.131726f, 0.131726f, 0.12435f, 1.0f}, sizeof BpfHX_iir1.A);
  ...
}
```

Or the old fashion way:

```
  const float A0[MAX_STAGES_IIR] = {0.131726f, 0.131726f, 0.12435f, 1.0f};
  memcpy(BpfHX_iir1.A, A0, sizeof BpfHX_iir1.A);
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> *Arrays* cannot be simply assigned in C.  They can be copied via `memcpy()`, just like any object.

Comment: thank you, I forgot that **memcpy()** function.

Comment: `memcpy` is almost never the correct solution for embedded systems programs however. Most often you'll just want to swap two buffer pointers instead.